How to retrieve Wazuh API
Currently our team is working on an python script for automated reports for Wazuh, but there seems to be a problem with the API tokens, we followed the steps given in the Wazuh documentation on how to retrieve the Wazuh API, but we still encounter an error and could not fetch any data from our Wazuh Manager.
How can I fix it? Or how we can properly retrieve/use the Wazuh API token?
This is the error we get whenever we run the script:

Error fetching data: 401


Here is our script:
import os
from datetime import datetime
from fpdf import FPDF
import requests
import urllib3

# Suppress SSL warnings (if needed for testing, but avoid in production)
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# Wazuh API details
api_url = "https://10.255.255.21"  # Replace with your server IP or domain
endpoint = "/security/events"
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3YXp1aCIsImF1ZCI6IldhenVoIEFQSSBSRVNUIiwibmJmIjoxNzMyNjAyNzgwLCJleHAiOjE3MzI2MDM2ODAsInN1YiI6IndhenVoIiwicnVuX2FzIjpmYWxzZSwicmJhY19yb2xlcyI6WzFdLCJyYmFjX21vZGUiOiJ3aGl0ZSJ9.ABsFfykJS4X7JaGzfG-QvuRWyb4ib6NHYBMXy_Hs3d4he-317nAQhCs37A9YCTVSSMgxeQ8CvsTWw5M1t5Ncywd3AG3U2myDQF0fJ6PFkSnJ-d6iP6W6LCo-M_wdW13ntjc0D0Kuy-L0gL3FrDVox1MzDF44XblKjqnpbTW7G59UdCMU',  # Replace with your token
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Fetch alerts data from the Wazuh API
try:
    response = requests.get(f"{api_url}{endpoint}?limit=50", headers=headers, verify=False)  # Change verify=True to validate SSL certificate
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors
    data = response.json()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(f"Error fetching data: {err}")
    exit()

# Create PDF Report
class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14)
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Wazuh Alerts Report', border=False, ln=True, align='C')

    def chapter_title(self, title):
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        self.cell(0, 10, title, ln=True, align='L')

    def chapter_body(self, body):
        self.set_font('Arial', '', 10)
        self.multi_cell(0, 10, body)

pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()

# Check if 'data' and 'alerts' keys exist in the response
if 'data' in data and 'alerts' in data['data']:
    for alert in data['data']['alerts']:
        alert_id = alert.get('id', 'N/A')
        severity = alert.get('rule', {}).get('level', 'N/A')
        description = alert.get('rule', {}).get('description', 'No description available')
        timestamp = alert.get('timestamp', 'N/A')
        rule = alert.get('rule', {}).get('id', 'N/A')

        pdf.chapter_title(f"Alert ID: {alert_id}")
        body = (
            f"Rule ID: {rule}\n"
            f"Description: {description}\n"
            f"Severity: {severity}\n"
            f"Timestamp: {timestamp}"
        )
        pdf.chapter_body(body)
else:
    print("No alerts found in the response.")
    exit()

# Save report to a dedicated folder with a timestamped filename
output_folder = os.path.expanduser("~/wazuh_reports")
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
filename = f"{output_folder}/wazuh_alerts_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.pdf"
pdf.output(filename)
print(f"Report saved to {filename}")


or you can check it here:
https://github.com/jmlessrobbery/Wazuh-Scripts/blob/main/generate_wazuh_report.py
Edit: I included our script in the post

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
